# How do I ask SQLite if a column contains a string?

Tags: sql, sqlite, pattern-matching

Normally in order to ask SQLite whether a column contains a string, I would use a query along the lines of: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%' || ? || '%'`.

The main problem is what if the string I am searching for is `%`?

I currently escape the string I am searching for with something like `str_replace(search, '%, '%%')`. When I apply to the simple string of `%` this yeilds a like string of `%%%%` which is two escaped percents. Also, what happens for a string that starts with the escape character, e.g. `%hello` would result in `%%%hello` which is an escaped `%` followed by any number of characters followed by hello.

I could change the escape character, but then the new escape character would have the same problem.

Note: I know I can use instr, but I was wondering if there is a solution to this with LIKE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot escape the LIKE pattern characters `_`and `%` just by doubling them.

According to [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like), you can add an ESCAPE clause to define a character that removes the special meaning of the following character:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn LIKE '%' || ? || '%' ESCAPE '@'
```

Then the search string `%hello` would have to be escaped as `@%hello`; similarly, `chacham15@example.org` would have to be escaped as `chacham15@@example.org`.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Thanks for clearing that confusion up.

Comment: What if the wildcard character happens to be the escape character? In that case %% would effectively translate to %.

Comment: @CL. Well, single quotes are escaped by doubling them.

Comment: SQL's string parsing and LIKE's pattern matching work differently.